# WMI Process Owner when process finishes

Tags: process, vbscript, wmi

I have the following code where I am trying to gather rich information about processes in Windows Server 2003. My problem occurs when I'm trying to pull back the process owner for a process which finishes between the initial WMI query and the call to get the owner. If the process has finished in the mean time then an error is raised and the script stops. I'd rather just check if the process is not available and not output to the console if it isn't. I've looked at the reference and there doesn't seem to be an appropriate method for this. Any help much appreciated.

The error raised is...

### **`getProcessInfo2.vbs(42, 5) SWbemObjectEx: Not found`**

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"_
     & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process",,48) 

For Each objItem in colItems 

    'Calculated Fields
    sngProcessTime = ( CSng(objItem.KernelModeTime) + CSng(objItem.UserModeTime)) / 10000000


    Wscript.Echo
    Wscript.Echo "ProcessId                  : " & objItem.ProcessId
    Wscript.Echo "CommandLine                : " & objItem.CommandLine
    Wscript.Echo "CreationDate               : " & objItem.CreationDate
    Wscript.Echo "HandleCount                : " & objItem.HandleCount
    Wscript.Echo "Name                       : " & objItem.Name
    Wscript.Echo "PageFaults                 : " & objItem.PageFaults
    Wscript.Echo "PageFileUsage              : " & objItem.PageFileUsage
    Wscript.Echo "ParentProcessId            : " & objItem.ParentProcessId
    Wscript.Echo "PeakPageFileUsage          : " & objItem.PeakPageFileUsage
    Wscript.Echo "PeakVirtualSize            : " & objItem.PeakVirtualSize
    Wscript.Echo "PeakWorkingSetSize         : " & objItem.PeakWorkingSetSize
    Wscript.Echo "Priority                   : " & objItem.Priority
    Wscript.Echo "QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     : " & objItem.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage
    Wscript.Echo "QuotaPagedPoolUsage        : " & objItem.QuotaPagedPoolUsage
    Wscript.Echo "QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : " & objItem.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage
    Wscript.Echo "QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    : " & objItem.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage
    Wscript.Echo "ReadOperationCount         : " & objItem.ReadOperationCount
    Wscript.Echo "ReadTransferCount          : " & objItem.ReadTransferCount
    Wscript.Echo "ThreadCount                : " & objItem.ThreadCount
    Wscript.Echo "VirtualSize                : " & objItem.VirtualSize
    Wscript.Echo "WriteOperationCount        : " & objItem.WriteOperationCount
    Wscript.Echo "WriteTransferCount         : " & objItem.WriteTransferCount
    Wscript.Echo "CPUTime                    : " & sngProcessTime

    Dim Return
    Return = objItem.GetOwner(strNameOfUser)
    If Return <> 0 Then strNameOfUser = "unavailable"

    Wscript.Echo "Owner                      : " & strNameOfUser    
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check whether your collection item still contains a valid WMI object reference.  If the WMI object no longer exists, your reference will become null.

```
For Each objItem in colItems
    If IsObject(objItem) Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```